# django get number of queries of all applications on my site?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

How to get the number of queries of all applications on my site?

I have used scrapy and django. By scrapy I tried to request all the urls and by django middleware I thought I could count the number of queries. But on making request, the errors I faced were

1) I was unable to configure the scrapy settings for django.

2) I tried using management command but it won't help because it is a scrapy project not a django application?

So how could I request all the urls of my site and log the number of queries of each application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.
Is "each apllication" a django application?

In case of django application, to log number of queries of all views in all aplication, add a simple middleware with `process_view` method. Here you will can to get view module name and save number of queries for each of module.
I think you should use redis to store this information for perfomance reasons.

Something like this:

```
class SaveCountOfViewRequestsMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        redis_client.incr(view_func.__module__)
```